# GLES30.glBufferData crash

Tags: android, opengl-es

When I program a project on Android with GLES 3.0 VBO, sometimes the application crashes when it invoking the method GLES30.glBufferData. There is no crashes happen if I use simple data while it crash when I get data from file.

```
int[] vboIDs = new int[1];
GLES30.glGenBuffers(1, vboIDs, 0);
GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIDs[0]);
GLES30.glBufferData(GLES30.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, buffer, GLES30.GL_STATIC_DRAW);//size=1296 buffer.capacity()=1296
GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

It just crashed with no exception log. Is the format of *buffer* wrong? Below is how I get the *buffer* instance,the parameter byteBuffer is got from a binary file,

```
 public static ByteBuffer createSlice(
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer, int position, int length)
{
    if (byteBuffer == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    int oldPosition = byteBuffer.position();
    int oldLimit = byteBuffer.limit();
    try
    {
        int newLimit = position + length;
        if (newLimit > byteBuffer.capacity())
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "The new limit is " + newLimit + ", but the capacity is "
                + byteBuffer.capacity());
        }
        byteBuffer.limit(newLimit);
        byteBuffer.position(position);
        ByteBuffer slice = byteBuffer.slice();
        slice.order(byteBuffer.order());
        return slice;
    }
    finally
    {
        byteBuffer.limit(oldLimit);
        byteBuffer.position(oldPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if there are any errors with `glGetError`?

Comment: I added `glGetError` after `glBufferData`,but it just crashes without invoke `glGetError`

Answer (score 0):

A crash in buffer data normally means you've run off the end of the buffer and accessed an unmapped page, so check that `size` is correct for the `buffer` you are uploading.

Comment: `size=1296 buffer.capacity()=1296`,I found where the problem is, the `buffer` has no data. Thanks.